# I'm trying to delete cells in excel as their values are rendered blank from another function

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to delete the blank cells and shift the remaining cells up as they are deleted. The cells that are deleted don't necessarily go from top down; they could appear anywhere in the list.

There have been similar questions, but mine is specific to just the cell not the whole row.

An image example of where cells would need to be deleted in column I.

[image]

-thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking - is the relationship between cells on a single row not important? So in the example you've given, Antonio Brown (on row 4) should be shifted up to row 2 (or 1?) and 5 (on row 5) would be shifted up to the same row, so that row 2 would read `ARI`, `8`, `RB`, `Antonio Brown`, `5`. Is that correct?

Comment: @jack-cccc: I downvoted/VTC because [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [no research was done](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) was not included

Comment: The relationship is not important, because the column 'I' is a mirror column to another column. It's serves as a selection pool for another macro. In the example Antonio Brown would be shifted to row 2, and ODell would be shifted to 3 etc etc. @IsaacReefman

Comment: @JackCccc Did you check my answer below? It does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the blank cells by `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` and then delete these cells in any specific column.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteBlankCells()
    Workbooks("Sheet1").Columns("I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```